# Do I need a permit to renovate a porch in NYC?

Tags: deck, code-compliance, replacement

I want to renovate my 2nd floor porch, but I don't know if NYC requires a permit. My house was built in 1901, and I believe a CO is not needed because of the grandfather clause. But if I make any alterations, will it be an issue if I want to sell my house and don't have a CO?

Does changing the size of the porch also require an engineer or architect be involved? If I kept it the same size, but made slight improvements, would that help me circumvent needing the city's approval?

I've never been through the process of applying for a permit, and I don't know what it all entails. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You generally need a permit to get out of bed or pick your nose in NYC.

Comment: Most jurisdictions have something like a *certificate of existing use* for structures built before Cs of O were required. When you try to sell you may need a cursory inspection to make sure it's not a deathtrap, but nothing like a full blown C of O inspection. You may need a C of O for any new work done post building code.

Comment: @iLikeDirt "Sir, put the high capacity magazine clip ghost keyboard down. No one NEEDS a keyboard with more than 7 keys to post their extremist opinions on the internet. This is your last warning."

Comment: This... is a GHOST RENOVATION

Answer (score 2):

At the point where someone wonders,  "Is a building permit required?" the answer is usually, Yes.

The only definitive answer will come from the local building department.

Answer (score 2):

As a highly-regulated hobby, pretty much everything about DIY remodeling requires a permit. This is generally more true the more structural the project and the bluer the state you live in. However, among DIYers, permit requirements are commonly ignored with no consequences, usually because nobody can see you doing the work. However, common sense dictates that if the project you are considering is sufficiently complicated or extreme that you feel like you might need to go get a permit, what you probably *actually* need is professional help, and the professional you hire will pull any required permits for you.

Now, to apply this to your situation: you're looking at possible structural modifications to a second-story porch on a hundred-year-old house in one of the most highly regulated and bureaucratized cities in America where privacy is a distant memory. Darn right you're going to need a permit. You're also probably going to want to hire a pro so you don't kill yourself, unless the modifications you're considering involve anything more drastic than repainting. Said pro will helpfully pull the permit for you, double the price he paid to do so, add it onto your bill, and pocket the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Location specific advice is generally considered off topic as per the [faq] but, that said...

Pretty much anything you do to a building "requires" a permit.  Whether or not you actually GET one is a different question, but a blanket "yes, probably" applies here.

But that said - a permit only applies to the work being done.  If you get a permit for a new electrical line in the front room, and don't touch the line to the 2nd floor light in the back, the existing work is almost always automatically grandfathered "as is".  The general rule is if you TOUCH it, it has to be brought to code.

So the CO question does not apply because:

1. You don't put CO detectors on a porch (no point)
2. The porch renovation won't have anything to do with the basement

Comment: CO in this case probably means "[Certificate of Occupancy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_of_occupancy)".

Comment: Oh well that's different...  --- whoops.